# Armature bones type, after Diffeomorphic plugin import

Tags: animation, rigging, import

Good day,

Newbie question, but after importing scene from DAZ3D with help of Diffeomorphic plugin, armature bones are something totally different(not coned and greenish, picture attached).
My question is - what kind of bones are these and how can they be returned back to standard bones?[image]

I'm trying to find stable way to utilize DAZ3d poses and use them on Blender armature, but so far Blender does not recognize exported FBX/DAE/BVH properly.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about external addons are off-topic here, however that looks like just a display setting:

On the <kbd>Object Data</kbd> tab (1) of your armature under <kbd>Viewport Display</kbd>, <kbd>Display as</kbd> is probably set to <kbd>Stick</kbd> (2).

[image]

The default is <kbd>Octahedral</kbd> which you can change on the dropdown:

[image]

In addition as Gordon Brinkman has commented the bone colours are probably due to <kbd>Bone Group Colors</kbd>. If you go into <kbd>Pose</kbd> mode you'll probably find a group in the <kbd>Bone</kbd><kbd>Groups</kbd>. At the R/H end of the name, clicking the icon will bring up a Color Set dropdown and you can set the bone colors of the bone group there. If you right-click on that icon you can click <kbd>Reset to Default</kbd> to revert to the standard colour.

[image]

Comment: Additionally, the question about the color: most likely the bones are assigned to a bone group which was given a green bone group color set.

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann. Now added to my answer.

Comment: Just to add a little about color: this was not just color group, but added bone contstraints to restrict bone movements and rotation to some limit. And currectly struggling to remove them all at once from all bones, but Blender does not allow that by default by selecting all bones and removing bone property - it removes only from first selected.

Comment: There probably is a way to do it in one go, but we'd need to see your Blend file whcih you could share via https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Blend-file kindly attached:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Jd1Xe8aK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Jd1Xe8aK/)

Comment: I've added the file link directly into your question. I guess that one could remove all bone constraints by iterating through all the bones and remove them using python, but I'm not familiar with using python in Blender so someone else woud have to answer that.